# Anyone knows an algorithm that finds minimum distance for all permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets of the same size $n$. Let $P(A),P(B)$ be the set of all permutations of $A,B$ respectively. A distance function $d(a,b)$ is defined for any $P(a)\in A,P(b)\in B$. We want to find $\min \{d(a,b):a\in P(A), b\in P(B)\}$ for a fixed $d$.

For example, suppose we have two sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$, and the distance $d$ is Euclidean distance, then all possible distance values are

> $d((1,2),(3,4)) = \sqrt8$
>
> $d((1,2),(4,3))=\sqrt {10}$
>
> $d((2,1),(3,4)) = \sqrt{10}$
>
> $d((2,1),(4,3)) = \sqrt{8}$

So the minimum is $\sqrt 8$.

I think this is a very common problem so there should be some known approach out there. Anyone knows an efficient algorithm to solve this problem and help provide the name or reference? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the minimum be taken over all $a\in P(A)$ and $b\in P(B)$?